# Testing for exceptions being raised

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm new to ruby. Trying to write a test that passes when an exception is raised, for example:

```
 def network_data_unavailable
    assert_raise StandardError, NetworkSim.sim(totalUse, 3, "five")
  end
```

Those inputs will cause a StandardError to be raised but my test still fails. Any help on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think the method you're looking for is `assert_raises`, not `assert_raise`. Then you need to call it correctly [by giving it a block](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/seattlerb/minitest/Minitest/Assertions#assert_raises-instance_method):

> **#assert_raises(*exp) ⇒ Object**
>
> Fails unless the block raises one of `exp`. Returns the exception matched so you can check the message, attributes, etc.
> [...]
>
> ```
> assert_raises(CustomError) { method_with_custom_error }
> ```

You want to say:

```
assert_raises StandardError do
  NetworkSim.sim(totalUse, 3, "five")
end
```

so that `assert_raises` can call the block after it has set up the exception handling. They way you're calling it, `NetworkSim.sim` will be called while building the argument list to `assert_raises` and the exception will be raised before `assert_raises` can do anything to catch it.